# Why is there is a change in data items during learner.autofit using BERT?

Tags: python-3.x, bert-language-model

I am trying to fit BERT text classifier. My training and test data looks as follows.

```
x_train = data["TEXT"].head(4500).tolist()
y_train= [label2id[label] for label in data["EMOTION"].head(4500).values.tolist()]
x_test = data["TEXT"].tail(500).tolist()
y_test = [label2id[label] for label in data["EMOTION"].tail(500).values.tolist()]
```

Then, I download the pretrained BERT model (uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12.zip)...

```
(x_train,  y_train), (x_test, y_test), preproc = text.texts_from_array(x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train,
                                                                       x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test,
                                                                       class_names=data['EMOTION'].unique().tolist(),
                                                                       preprocess_mode='bert',
                                                                       ngram_range=1, 
                                                                       maxlen=350, 
                                                                       max_features=35000)
```

For classification, we set the bert model as

```
model = text.text_classifier('bert', train_data=(x_train, y_train), preproc=preproc)
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=(x_train, y_train), batch_size=6)
```

Finally, I try fit to the model using 1cycle policy rate

```
hist = learner.fit_onecycle(2e-5, 1)
```

I get the result with 750 samples rather than 4500 samples. I also tested this with various data. So there is always variations in data items. Can you give an idea what is behind it?

```
begin training using onecycle policy with max lr of 2e-05...
750/750 [==============================] - 875s 1s/step - loss: 0.3740 - accuracy: 0.8544
```

Thank you for your response in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal idea is that when you instantiate the learner with `ktrain.get_learner` you give it a `batch size = 6` as input parameter.

So when you try to train the learner by simply doing `learner.fit_onecycle (2e-5, 1)`, it takes exactly one batch for training, in fact `4500 training data / batch size (6) = 750` data to train on.

At this point either try to change the batch size, or do a for loop like this:

```
for epoch in range(X):
    ....
    for batch in chunker(train, batch_size):
    ....
```

where `chunker()` could be something like:

```
def chunker(sequence, size):
    """useful for splitting a sequence into minibatches"""
    for i in range(0, len(sequence), size):
        chunk = sequence[i:i+size]
        # sort sentences in batch by length in descending order
        chunk.sort(key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
        yield chunk
```

In a nutshell the idea is that you have to do a loop in which you go to select each time a set of data (batch) that you want to use to train your model.